# What are the different ways to call a jsp from an HTML page?

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, servlets

I'm new on JSP and I have a basic question.
For the moment, i only know two ways to call a Servlet from HTML code.

Call doPost or doGet :

```
<form action"servletName" method="POST">
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

or

```
<form action"servletName" method="GET">
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Call doGet :

```
<a href="servletName"></a>
```

Is there some others ?

Comment: Change `servletName` to `jspName.jsp` - every JSP **is-a** servlet (a JSP file is compiled into a servlet to be executed). And the generic method of servlet is `doRequest`. There are other verbs beside get and post, what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: using [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)  ?